# Code splitting doesn't work with webpack 4 and razzlejs

Tags: javascript, webpack, server-side-rendering, code-splitting

I am trying to use webpack 4 code splitting  with razzle js.
I was following example in [razzlejs github page](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/tree/master/examples/with-vendor-bundle) , but it isn't working correctly.

razzle.config.js file:

```
if (target === 'web') {
  appConfig.output.filename = dev ? 'static/js/[name].js' : 'static/js/[name].[hash:8].js';
  appConfig.entry.vendor = [
        require.resolve('razzle/polyfills'),
        require.resolve('react'),
        require.resolve('react-dom'),
  ];
  appConfig.optimization = {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false
    }
  };
...
```

.env file:

```
REACT_DEV_BUNDLE_PATH=/static/js/vendor.js
```

template file:

```
const scripts = Object.keys(assets).reduce((scripts, key) => {
  return scripts + `<script src="${assets[key].js}" defer crossorigin></script>`;
}, '');

return `
<!doctype html>
<html lang="${currentLanguage}">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>${title}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ${scripts}
</head>
...
`
```

It seems that react and other libs aren't included in final vendor.js file. 
Can somebody help me with this, thanks.

Comment: Did you figure it out by chance?

Comment: Yes, in **razzle.config.js** I just add:
`
        // optimization
        appConfig.optimization = {
          ...baseConfig.optimization,
          minimizer: [...baseConfig.optimization.minimizer, new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
          splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            name: false
          },
          removeEmptyChunks: true,
          runtimeChunk: false
        };
`